# Why can $Q$ be calculated by $f_0/f_{FWHM}$?

Tags: resonance, microwaves, cavity-qed

I found this expression for the reflection signal of a microwave cavity:

$$
|\Gamma|^2(f) = 1-\frac{1-\Delta M}{\left(2Q\left(\frac{f}{f_0}-1\right)\right)^2+1},
$$
with $f$ the frequency, $f_0$ the resonance frequency, $Q$ the $Q$-factor of the resonator and $\Delta M$ the impedance mismatch, basically the distance between $0$ and the deepest point of the resonance profile. According to all sources I found $Q$ is in turn related to the $FWHM$ of the resonance as $$Q=\frac{f_0}{f_{FWHM}} .$$ However, at frequency $f=f_0\pm\frac{f_{FWHM}}{2}$ we have $$|\Gamma|^2(f=f_0\pm\frac{f_{FWHM}}{2}) = \frac{1+\Delta M}{2}.$$ If you solve this equation for $Q$ I seem to get $$Q=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{f_0}{f_{FWHM}}.$$ Am I missing something? Am I using conflicting definitions?

Comment: Yes, there is no single agreed upon definition for the $Q$ factor. It is common for different definition to differ by factors of order unity. It's not clear what definition you're using for $Q$ at the bottom of your post.

Comment: $Q=f_0/f_{FWHM}$ is the known, standard definition. The one on the bottom with the extra factor $1/\sqrt{2}$ is what follows from the top equation.